# Need help using Accelerometer in iOS

Tags: ios, avaudioplayer, accelerometer

I am working on an app that would play a beep for each position the user holds their iOS device (standing, lying on its front/back, or on its side).  At the moment, I am able to play a sound when the user has the device on its side, however, the problem is that because I have the accelerometer values linked with the slider, the beeping sound is continuous (i.e. it plays the sound as long as the user is holding the device on its side), rather than just once.

I would like the user to simply hold the device steady on its side, and then a single beep sound is made, allowing the user to then hold the device in the other positions in turn, and wait for another beep sound.  I want the user to go step by step by step and hold the device in each position one at a time, moving on to the next position only after hearing a beep.

Here is the code that I am working with:

```
- (void)accelerometer:(UIAccelerometer *)accelerometer didAccelerate:(UIAcceleration *)acceleration
{

    NSLog(@"(%.02f, %.02f, %.02f)", acceleration.x, acceleration.y, acceleration.z);
    slider.value = acceleration.x;

    if (slider.value == -1)
        [self pushBeep];

    else if (slider.value == 0.00)
        [self pushBap];

    else if (slider.value == 1)
        [self pushBop];

...
```

and here is the code for my pushBeep() method (FYI, the methods pushBeep/pushBap/pushBop are all identical):

```
-(void) pushBeep {

    NSString *soundPath =[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"beep-7" ofType:@"wav"];
    NSURL *soundURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:soundPath];

    NSError *ierror = nil;
    iPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:soundURL error:&ierror];

    [iPlayer play];
}
```

Can anyone figure out what is the problem here?

Comment: The accelrometer keeps chnaging its values even if your Phone is static. I guess it's because of sensitivity of device to gravity so your beep will be continuous always.

Comment: Isn't it possible for me to simply play the sound once it hits a particular position, and then break/quit?  Could that work?

Comment: Why do you not keep in a variable because of which value was the last sound ? If the current value is different from the last one and is equal to one of your trigger value, play the sound and save it...

Comment: Why do you have to use the accelerometer value instead of UIInterfaceOrientation changes or UIDeviceOrientation changes?

Comment: I think I understand what you're saying, but could you clarify a bit so that I fully comprehend your suggestion?

Comment: @Ryan, I haven't used UIInterfaceOrientation nor UIDeviceOrientation changes before.  Would they work as I am describing?

Comment: Check my answer. gave you an option on both.

Comment: @Ryan, thanks very much for your solution!  Could you please clarify what you meant by "...or if you don't have a UIViewController"?  These tests will be done while the user is looking at a particular screen, and so I will need this code to work within a viewController.  Will this not be possible?

Comment: The first will work no matter what. The second method needs to be placed inside a UIViewController subclass. If you just have a simple app I assume you're using viewControllers. If you were doing something fully custom you may HAVE to use the first.

Comment: You also HAVE to use the first method if you need to check for FaceUp or FaceDown. There aren't UIInterfaceOrientations for FaceUp and FaceDown but there are UIDeviceOrientations for them. Subtle differences.

Comment: Thanks Abid, and Larme for your responses, and a special thanks to Ryan for your detailed response, and solution.  You're a gentleman, and a scholar!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think instead of manually polling the accelerometer you should use the built in Orientation Notifications. You could use something like the below if you needed FaceUp and FaceDown orientations. Or you can use the second method for simply landscape, portrait.

**First Method** that relies on the device orientation. Important if you need FaceUp or FaceDown orientations or if you don't have a UIViewController.

```
[[UIDevice currentDevice] beginGeneratingDeviceOrientationNotifications];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]
   addObserver:self selector:@selector(orientationChanged:)
   name:UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification
   object:[UIDevice currentDevice]];
```

And here is the method to build.

```
- (void) orientationChanged:(NSNotification *)note
{
   UIDevice * device = note.object;
   switch(device.orientation)
   {
       case UIDeviceOrientationPortrait:
       /* Play a sound */
       break;

       case UIDeviceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown:
       /* Play a sound */
       break;

       // ....

       default:
       break;
   };
}
```

**Second Method** that relies on interfaceOrientations of a UIViewController.

```
- (void)willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration
{
    switch (toInterfaceOrientation) {
        case UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft:
            /* Play a Sound */
            break;

        case UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait:
            /* Play a Sound */
            break;

            // .... More Orientations

        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Accelerometer comes from the word acceleration - it won't tell you the orientation of the device, it will tell you the speed at which it has moved in space on x, y and z-axis only. 
Use UIInterfaceOrientation && UIDeviceOrientation.